# $_COOKIE suddently does not return any value

Tags: php, session-cookies

I have recently have a problem with some code who used to run perfectly for 6 month and suddenly yesterday the page went blank! After some debug i found that the cause was the $_COOKIE. I have a cookie variable : $_COOKIE['company']; that used to return a number but now doesn't return nothing. I have no idea why did this happened! I didn't change a thing in this file..
What can be the cause for a cookie not to return a value anymore?

Any idea is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the cookie in your web browser expired. Probably a login page somewhere on your site that will reset it.

Comment: or the domain changed, or the protocol changed